# CSS Sprite for a href not initially showing up

Tags: css, sprite

I'm trying to use a CSS sprite on some anchor tags. However, when I load my page, what should be the "initial" icon doesn't show up!! Any ideas? I double checked my image paths and they are indeed correct. I'm not sure if my coordinates for the background position are 100% correct, but I figured I can tweak those once I actually get the icon to show up! Thanks!

HTML:

```
 <div id="social">
<a href="https://www.behance.net/lb155edc6" target="_blank" class="button"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#social a.button{
width:150px;
height:150px;
display:block;
background-image:url('images/icons/behancesprite.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:0 0;
 }
#social a.button:hover{
background-position: 0 -266px;
}
```

Comment: Check your console to see if there's an error loading that image. Also, http://www.spritecow.com/ is great for getting css positioning on sprites. Your code looks good.

Comment: Thanks, Christopher! It turns out there was a stupid error, I've fixed it. Thanks!